# insert vriable into table QGIS

Tags: python, sql, qgis

I'm trying to insert some values in a data base table that I created with the following code:

```
conn = db.connect('test.sqlite')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sql= 'SELECT InitSpatialMetadata()'
    cur.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
#connection to the DB

qid=QInputDialog()    
tablefacette,ok=QInputDialog.getText(qid,u'Table name',None,QLineEdit.Normal,None)
tablefacette=str(tablefacette)
#asking user for a table name

cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s' %tablefacette)
    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE %s (IDface INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Xp1 FLOAT NOT NULL, \
    Yp1 FLOAT NOT NULL, Zp1 FLOAT NOT NULL, Xp2 FLOAT NOT NULL, Yp2 FLOAT NOT NULL, \
    Zp2 FLOAT NOT NULL, Xp3 FLOAT NOT NULL, Yp3 FLOAT NOT NULL, Zp3 FLOAT NOT NULL)' %tablefacette)
#creation of the table

    for i in range(0,len(IDface)):
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO %s" %tablefacette, "(IDface, Xp1, Yp1, Zp1, Xp2, Yp2, Zp2, Xp3, Yp3, Zp3) VALUES \
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (IDface[i], Xp1[i], Yp1[i], Zp1[i],  Xp2[i], Yp2[i], Zp2[i],  Xp3[i], Yp3[i], Zp3[i]))
        conn.commit()
#filling the table with values Xp[i] etc which come from a list that I created
```

The problem comes from the %s using in the last cur.execute, this function takes at most 2 arguments but there are 3 because of the %s using. So do you have a solution or an idea to help me? I would like to fill my list with the name given by the user and fill it with the values which come from tables.

Thank you for your attention to this matter!

Answer (score 0):

I would write like this instead:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO %s (IDface, Xp1, Yp1, Zp1, Xp2, Yp2, Zp2, Xp3, Yp3, Zp3) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", %(table_name, Xp1[i], Yp1[i], Zp1[i],  Xp2[i], Yp2[i], Zp2[i],  Xp3[i], Yp3[i], Zp3[i]))
```